# ASP.NET MVC with AJAX doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is what I'm trying to achieve :

View1 sends `name` string to View2, View2 sends JSON to View1 and View1 parses it and displays data.

View1 sends name string to View2 like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

                var myurl = "/Controller/View2";

                $("form").submit(function (event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: myurl,
                        data: $('#nameid').val(),
                        success: function (newdata) {
```

View2 is a controller that returns JSON :

```
        public ActionResult View2(string nameid)
        {


    //do stuff


            return Json(jsObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

View1 controller is something like this :

```
    public ActionResult View1(string nameid)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameid))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("View2", new { nameid = nameid });
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

I don't know which part I messed up but when I click submit, it displays the JSON object itself. How can I fix this situation? Thanks.

EDIT : 
Here is my View1 view (I don't have a View for View2 controller) :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/cytoscape.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    #cy {
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        position: center;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
</style>
<body>

    <form>
        Enter a name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="nameid" id="nameid" value="">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send!">
    </form> 

    <div id="cy"></div>
    <script>

        var myVar = null


        $(document).ready(function () {



            $("form").submit(function (event) {
                //event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/Controller/View2",
                   data: { nameid: $('#nameid').val() },
                    success: function (newdata) {

                        var cy = cytoscape({


                            container: document.getElementById("cy"),
                            elements: JSON.parse(newdata)

                        });

                    }
                });

            });


        });



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the url you have specified is correct.

`var myurl = "/Controller/View2";`

as you have an action named `MainGraph2`

Also, you would not be able to redirect from an Ajax call. So try redirecting in the Ajax success callback function.

Also, as mentioned in the other answers, you should pass your data to controller as below:

```
data: { nameid: $('#nameid').val() },
```

**Edit**

Everything looks perfect, please try the below:

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Sample/View2",
        data: { nameid: $('#nameid').val() },
        success: function (newdata) {
            $("#cy").val(newdata);
         }
     });
  });
```

Here Sample (**url: "/Sample/View2"**) is the controller name (*SampleController*).
Also, please make sure you don't call the view id with the nameid as parameter as in

```
http://localhost/Sample/View1?nameid=Jason
```

if it is called in such a way, it would be returing json data.

**Note**: I have named my controller as SampleController and **cy** as input type of text.

Comment: I corrected the question. It should be `View2`. I did what you said but it's still the same.

Comment: I believe form post is happening instead of the intended Ajax call. Could you please check/share the view so that we can get a better idea.

Comment: I added my View. I don't have a View for View2 controller. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The point that I don't understand is why am I seeing `View2` action in my URL? How can I make my code stay only in `View1` action? Thanks.

Comment: Also when I add `event.preventDefault();`, it doesn't work at all. I mean it does nothing.

Comment: `$.submit()` is called before the default form submit. Since you have commented out `event.preventDefault()` the default form is also getting posted and the page is getting redirected. Hence you are seeing the view2 url. You would see the same if you type in `http://localhost/Sample/View1?nameid=Jason`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143150/discussion-between-gvk-and-jason).

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to prevent the normal form submission.

Second, for your `nameid` value to bind to action parameter, it has to be given the proper name.

Third. Do you have a controller class named `ControllerController`?

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var myurl = '@Url.Content("~/Controller/View2")';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: myurl,
    data: { nameid: $('#nameid').val() },
    success: function (newdata) {
      console.log(newdata);
      // ...
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + status + " - " + error);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Could you give an example? I couldn't understand it. I'm sorry.

Comment: When I add `event.preventDefault();`, nothing happens. When I delete that line, it still displayes JSON data

Comment: at the time when JSON is displayed in the browser, what is the url in the address bar?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to rewrite the ajax like this and have a try.

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Controller/View2',
                data:{ 
                       nameid: $('#nameid').val()
                      },
                success: function (newdata) {
```